# Generic container: why do I need an interface?

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have the following

```
public interface IInterval<T>
{
    T Start { get; }
    T Stop  { get; }
}

public class DateTimeInterval : IInterval<DateTime>
{
    private DateTime _start;
    private DateTime _stop;

    public DateTimeInterval(DateTime start, DateTime stop)
    {
        _start = start; _stop = stop;
    }

    public DateTime Start
    {
        get { return _start; }
    }
    public DateTime Stop
    {
        get { return _stop; }
    }
}

public class SortedIntervalList<T> 
    where T : IInterval<T>, IComparable<T>
{
}
```

If I were to now try to instantiate the container

```
var test = new SortedIntervalList<DateTimeInterval>();
```

I get a compilation error

> The type 'Test' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic
>   type or method `TestContainer<T>`. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'Test' to `ITest<Test>`.

Why is this?

---

**Note on edit history**

For clarity, classes for the original question are included below

```
public interface ITest<T>
{
    int TestMethod();
}

public class Test : ITest<bool>
{

    public int TestMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TestContainer<T> 
    where T : ITest<T>
{ 

}
```

Comment: Actually it should _not_ compile fine.  You should have to add a generic constraint to `TestContainer<T>` so that it's compatible with the constraint on the `ITestContainer<T>` interface.

Comment: Why is `ITest<T>` generic when you never use `T` in the interface? just make it `public interface ITest {` instead and that will solve your problems (unless you do use `T`, in that case update the question to show how it is used). (Please also update `TestContainer` showing how it is used there too)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't think so, the updated examples still have the same underlying problem that both you and SLaks answers solve (reusing T in the constraint). But I don't want to start a edit war, I just ask you re-read it and if you change your mind then roll back your roll back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you expect your `T` in `TestContainer<T>` to be `ITest<T>`. that doesn't make sense. I think you meant :

```
public class TestContainer<C, T> 
where C : ITest<T>
{

}
```

---

For your updated code in your question:

```
public class SortedIntervalList<C, T> 
    where C : IInterval<T>, IComparable<T>
{ }
```

With:

```
test = new SortedIntervalList<DateTimeInterval, DateTime>();
```

Comment: I disagree -- I want something like List<T> but constrained to implement my interface.

Comment: @rookie yes, and if you want to do that, and have the interface be generic, you must have two type parameters passed in to `TestContainer`. Currently the only thing that would be allowed in would be `Test<Test>` because you used `T` both in the class definition and in the constraint.

Comment: Compare it to this: you ask `string` to be `List<string>`. No! Of course not. You expect `C` to be `List<string>`. Replace `string` with `T` and it becomes `C : List<T>`.

Comment: @rookie: update your `public class SortedIntervalList<T>` as in my answer and you will be fine.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Is there a way to expose the declaration in terms of just `DateTimeInterval`?

Comment: No. Then it should be `IInterval`, not `IInterval<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

```
where T : ITest<T>
```

Your class inherits `ITest<bool>`, which is not `ITest<T>` for your `T` (`Test`).
As the error is trying to tell you, that does not meet your generic constraint, so you can't do that.

Comment: I see. Is it a compiler requirement, then to define an interface for a generic container of generic objects? Is there any other way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "which is not `ITest<T>`" -- To be clear, it is `ITest<T>` for some `T`, but not the right `T`. `TestContainer<Test>` requires `Test` to implement `ITest<Test>` (like the error message says).

Comment: @rookie No, there's no compiler requirement that you implement an interface.  You've defined a constraint on `T` that the `Test` class does not meet (it must implement `ITest<Test>`).

Comment: @rookie: What are you trying to do?